# Order of Evaluation for function calls on the same line

Tags: c

I have this piece of code:

```
int get()
{
    static int i = 1;
    return i++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n", get(), get(), get());
    return 0;
}
```

And I thought the output would give me 1 2 3 but instead it returns 3 2 1. So my question is, how does the order of evaluation compute this? I read that it depends on the compiler so it can be either of the above but I am not so sure about the answer.

Comment: The order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified, meaning that the three calls to `get` could be executed in any order.

Comment: How can you specify which function arguments are evaluated first ?

Comment: Yes: with separate variables.  int arg1 = get(); int arg2 = get(); int arg3 = get(); and then use the arguments in printf.  Just the way it goes.